# using count to select total of rows from two table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables,

student = 150 (total no of rows which represent total no of student)

employer= 230 (total no of rows which represent total no of employer)

***FULL CODE***

```
<?php echo mysqli_num_rows($studempl); ?> 

$conn = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '', 'dashboard');
$studempl = $conn ->query ("SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employer) FROM    dual");
$tot_studempl = mysqli_num_rows($studempl);
```

Result: 1

How can i fix this?

**I tried to use**

```
SELECT 'student' AS stdID, COUNT(*) FROM student
UNION
SELECT 'employer' AS emplID, COUNT(*) FROM employer*
```

It displays the result = 2,

**I also tried to use:**

```
SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   student) AS count1,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   employer) AS count2 FROM    dual*
```

It displays the result = 1,

I think I might have wrong in my code,
how can I get total from student and from employer so i can view the data and display in piechart?

150, 230

Comment: `<?php echo mysqli_num_rows($studempl); ?>` well that being the first line of your code won't work since you're trying to show something that has yet to be executed, which you appear to be doing that below it.

Comment: thank you, i've fixed it, but it still display total of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the sum of the two tables in MySQL with a query like this

```
SELECT  ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scheme.student) + 
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scheme.employer) 
         ) AS 'Column' ;
```

In my case, i used the same table 2 times and that table has 280 rows ([280 x 2 = 560](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csR7Y.png)).

Hope this help you

Comment: hi, your code is helping me, it does display right total if i query it in mysql but why when i write done php, the total appear to be 1 in website? does this happen to you also? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You're second query should work.

```
    SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   student) AS count1,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM employer) AS count2 FROM    dual* <-- make sure you remove (*)
// so it should be like this 
    SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   student) AS count1,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM employer) AS count2 FROM    dual
```

Then you just have to fetch the array to display the results

```
$sql = "SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   playlists) AS count1,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   artists) AS count2 FROM    dual";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      var_dump($row); // just checking the raw array...
      echo "<br />";
      echo $row[0]. ", ". $row[1];  // got your results -> 150, 230
  }
mysqli_close($con);
```

Also, you're first query works if you replace the + to , like this

```
$sql = "SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employer) FROM    dual";
```

Comment: thank you, it help me to display my data. now i have to figure out how i want to display it in the piechart.